# Trigger validation and redraw on different component via ajax

Tags: ajax, wicket

I have a wicket page with a couple of TextFields that have different kind of validators. So far, validation is triggered via Ajax on the onChange event.

I also have a checkbox that defines which set of validation rules should be used for the TextFields.

If I click the checkbox and then input data into the TextFields, validation works just fine. But how do I handle the fact that already entered and validated data can suddenly become invalid if the checkbox is clicked afterwards? How do I trigger the validation and the redraw (to show the error notification) of the TextFields from within an AjaxEvent from the checkbox?

I tried to call myTextField.validate() but that didn't trigger any of my validators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your validation is based on multiple components you should implement [IFormValidator](http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.0.x/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/form/validation/IFormValidator.html). Pass both checkbox and textfield in `getDependentFormComponents()` and change of either will trigger it.

Also if you are using checkbox to refresh some elements make sure to use [AjaxCheckbox](http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.0.x/org/apache/wicket/ajax/markup/html/form/AjaxCheckBox.html), that has `onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget)` method.

Answer (score 0):

You could attach an AjaxFormSubmitBehavior in the checkbox. This would submit the form and trigger validation each time the checkbox value is toggled.